# How to clear data of a file before test run in cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

In Cypress, I'm using cy.writeFile() to store some data displaying on the page in a file.

The problem is that this data adds to the end of the file, but I don't want data from previous test runs to be there.

Is there any way for me to restart those data before each test run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always clear it by using `beforeEach` with a sample one below:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/myFile.txt', '') // clears the file before each tests
})

describe('my tests', ()=> {
  it('test 1', () => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/myFile.txt', 'print test 1')
  })
  it('test 2', () => {
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/myFile.txt', 'print test 2')
  })
})
```